# Ruby on Rails app on a Heroku environment: "Sending Email with Mailgun" error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, mailgun, cloud9

I was trying to test sending an e-mail from a contact form of a Rails app based at an Heroku server and I got an error saying:

*We're sorry, but something went wrong. If you are the application owner check the logs for more information.*

My intention was to learn how to integrate a mail server service into my Heroku account. For that, the addon used was MailGun. I even created a MailGun account with my personal e-mail to be able to check if I'm getting the e-mails or not.

After deploying the code from the Cloud9 environment to Heroku servers with the success, the only change I made in my Ruby code was the following stuff:

config/environment.rb

```
ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
  :port           => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PORT'],
  :address        => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_SERVER'],
  :user_name      => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_LOGIN'],
  :password       => ENV['MAILGUN_SMTP_PASSWORD'],
  :domain         => 'blahblahblah.herokuapp.com',
  :authentication => :plain,
}
ActionMailer::Base.delivery_method = :smtp
```

What's the problem? Any tip for a solution?

Updated Requested Info (Heroku Logs - I can't update all the logs due to restriction of characters in StackOverflow body):

```
iamsamuel:~/workspace/saasapp (master) $ heroku logs
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316716+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316717+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316718+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316718+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316719+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316719+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316720+00:00 app[web.1]:     <head>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316721+00:00 app[web.1]:     </head>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316721+00:00 app[web.1]:     <body>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316722+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316723+00:00 app[web.1]:             You have received a message from the site's contact form, from Sam, smlmrr@outlook.com.
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316724+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316724+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316725+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316725+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316726+00:00 app[web.1]:     </body>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316726+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316886+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.316838 #4]  INFO -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1166ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317316+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317273 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c]
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317357+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317318 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317358+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317396+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317355 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c]
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317435+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317396 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in `create'
2017-02-24T20:18:19.520898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=62153ff0-bef7-4e44-958b-447fb18e7c23 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:53:16.169251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-02-24T20:53:16.169901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-02-24T20:53:17.034264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078764+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078952+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-02-24 20:53:17 +0000 ===
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078957+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-02-24T20:53:17.079100+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-02-24T20:53:17.347515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-02-24T20:57:24.680979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-02-24T20:57:24.681258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-02-24T20:57:27.221989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 44473 -e production`
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299354+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299447+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44473
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299502+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229688+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229714+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229713+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229716+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229813+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:44473
2017-02-24T20:57:31.230029+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-24T20:57:31.421917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-24T20:57:32.788592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=2753
2017-02-24T20:57:32.737531+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.737424 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Started GET "/" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:57:32 +0000
2017-02-24T20:57:32.740219+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.740152 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2017-02-24T20:57:32.752357+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.752273 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-24T20:57:32.753153+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.753082 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:32.759595+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.759524 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:32.929609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-95163fa38446d1bb6139f870d5fb932af7fa47b347b8951923c32a4565386aa6.js" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=80d55a95-cbe8-4982-a571-bc8850567a87 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:32.928158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5ed627eba0abe94ba4e2c255c2298f55d9bca9b4ea45ded59ba1705edc5385d0.css" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=a9c456f3-e7cd-4d6a-865f-2c8f5efbdaa7 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:33.143930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-2932abf996373e87fbf2e950876b1962f1b57db954a1643ea68831d9fbb74da4.woff2?v=4.6.2" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=90d78563-eaa6-4f24-a054-5c89beada59c fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:33.402193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=7c20311c-bd5a-46c3-a9d5-c6266c1f9331 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:50.706814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact-us" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=4317
2017-02-24T20:57:50.651067+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.650984 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Started GET "/contact-us" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:57:50 +0000
2017-02-24T20:57:50.652579+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.652518 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2017-02-24T20:57:50.669618+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.669536 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb]   Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-24T20:57:50.681558+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.681481 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.8ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:50.682909+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.682846 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 14.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.426470+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.426395 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Started POST "/contacts" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:59:14 +0000
2017-02-24T20:59:14.427281+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.427232 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2017-02-24T20:59:14.427366+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.427324 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MgrtXM/8aUAYPnJ2ph4eIbsqMbLR/xXMZabcKmKh4myMlp0MdLJ2dCHnh7KshXSCqAsIzGQr0SdebpJw1v0QHw==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Jesse Pinkman", "email"=>"jp@example.com", "comments"=>"Yo Beach!"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2017-02-24T20:59:14.429694+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.429641 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
2017-02-24T20:59:14.434537+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.434485 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("name", "email", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Jesse Pinkman"], ["email", "jp@example.com"], ["comments", "Yo Beach!"], ["created_at", 2017-02-24 20:59:14 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-24 20:59:14 UTC]]
2017-02-24T20:59:14.436712+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.436665 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
2017-02-24T20:59:14.441776+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.441724 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb
2017-02-24T20:59:14.442284+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.442237 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.4ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.622612+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.622518 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 184.5ms
2017-02-24T20:59:14.749027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=304ms status=500 bytes=1669
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722589+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722491 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Sent mail to samuelslmoreira@hotmail.com (99.8ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722632+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722588 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 20:59:14 +0000
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722632+00:00 app[web.1]: From: jp@example.com
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722633+00:00 app[web.1]: To: samuelslmoreira@hotmail.com
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722633+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <58b09ea298a14_43fc0c75eb9c0103ae@71798652-2827-4935-9282-6b3ae7c47b44.mail>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722634+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Contact Form Message
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722634+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722636+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722636+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]:     <head>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]:     </head>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:     <body>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:             You have received a message from the site's contact form, from Jesse Pinkman, jp@example.com.
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]:     </body>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722825+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722779 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723286+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723242 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723324+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723287 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723325+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723357+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723324 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723390+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723357 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in `create'
iamsamuel:~/workspace/saasapp (master) $ clear
iamsamuel:~/workspace/saasapp (master) $ clear
iamsamuel:~/workspace/saasapp (master) $ heroku logs
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316723+00:00 app[web.1]:             You have received a message from the site's contact form, from Sam, smlmrr@outlook.com.
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316724+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316724+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316725+00:00 app[web.1]:             
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316725+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316726+00:00 app[web.1]:     </body>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316726+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-02-24T20:18:19.316886+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.316838 #4]  INFO -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1166ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317316+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317273 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c]   
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317357+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317318 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317358+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317396+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317355 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c]   
2017-02-24T20:18:19.317435+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:18:19.317396 #4] FATAL -- : [f024cbfb-df8b-4efa-8cb1-50a6a0d7881c] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in `create'
2017-02-24T20:18:19.520898+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=62153ff0-bef7-4e44-958b-447fb18e7c23 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:53:16.169251+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2017-02-24T20:53:16.169901+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2017-02-24T20:53:17.034264+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078764+00:00 app[web.1]: - Gracefully stopping, waiting for requests to finish
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078952+00:00 app[web.1]: === puma shutdown: 2017-02-24 20:53:17 +0000 ===
2017-02-24T20:53:17.078957+00:00 app[web.1]: - Goodbye!
2017-02-24T20:53:17.079100+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2017-02-24T20:53:17.347515+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 0
2017-02-24T20:57:24.680979+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2017-02-24T20:57:24.681258+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2017-02-24T20:57:27.221989+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 44473 -e production`
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299354+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Puma
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299447+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 5.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44473
2017-02-24T20:57:30.299502+00:00 app[web.1]: => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229688+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229714+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229713+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 3.4.0 (ruby 2.3.0-p0), codename: Owl Bowl Brawl
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229716+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2017-02-24T20:57:31.229813+00:00 app[web.1]: * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:44473
2017-02-24T20:57:31.230029+00:00 app[web.1]: Use Ctrl-C to stop
2017-02-24T20:57:31.421917+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2017-02-24T20:57:32.788592+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=58ms status=200 bytes=2753
2017-02-24T20:57:32.737531+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.737424 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Started GET "/" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:57:32 +0000
2017-02-24T20:57:32.740219+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.740152 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2017-02-24T20:57:32.752357+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.752273 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-24T20:57:32.753153+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.753082 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.6ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:32.759595+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:32.759524 #4]  INFO -- : [dedd394a-498a-464d-a669-ed19fa2fd418] Completed 200 OK in 19ms (Views: 8.6ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:32.929609+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-95163fa38446d1bb6139f870d5fb932af7fa47b347b8951923c32a4565386aa6.js" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=80d55a95-cbe8-4982-a571-bc8850567a87 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:32.928158+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5ed627eba0abe94ba4e2c255c2298f55d9bca9b4ea45ded59ba1705edc5385d0.css" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=a9c456f3-e7cd-4d6a-865f-2c8f5efbdaa7 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:33.143930+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-2932abf996373e87fbf2e950876b1962f1b57db954a1643ea68831d9fbb74da4.woff2?v=4.6.2" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=90d78563-eaa6-4f24-a054-5c89beada59c fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:33.402193+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=7c20311c-bd5a-46c3-a9d5-c6266c1f9331 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T20:57:50.706814+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/contact-us" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=35ms status=200 bytes=4317
2017-02-24T20:57:50.651067+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.650984 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Started GET "/contact-us" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:57:50 +0000
2017-02-24T20:57:50.652579+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.652518 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Processing by ContactsController#new as HTML
2017-02-24T20:57:50.669618+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.669536 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb]   Rendering contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-24T20:57:50.681558+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.681481 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb]   Rendered contacts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (11.8ms)
2017-02-24T20:57:50.682909+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:57:50.682846 #4]  INFO -- : [0ec752b1-0d75-42dd-83f6-ecd127086bfb] Completed 200 OK in 30ms (Views: 14.0ms | ActiveRecord: 7.5ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.426470+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.426395 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Started POST "/contacts" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 20:59:14 +0000
2017-02-24T20:59:14.427281+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.427232 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Processing by ContactsController#create as HTML
2017-02-24T20:59:14.427366+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.427324 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"MgrtXM/8aUAYPnJ2ph4eIbsqMbLR/xXMZabcKmKh4myMlp0MdLJ2dCHnh7KshXSCqAsIzGQr0SdebpJw1v0QHw==", "contact"=>{"name"=>"Jesse Pinkman", "email"=>"jp@example.com", "comments"=>"Yo Beach!"}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
2017-02-24T20:59:14.429694+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.429641 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]    (0.9ms)  BEGIN
2017-02-24T20:59:14.434537+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.434485 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   SQL (1.3ms)  INSERT INTO "contacts" ("name", "email", "comments", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5) RETURNING "id"  [["name", "Jesse Pinkman"], ["email", "jp@example.com"], ["comments", "Yo Beach!"], ["created_at", 2017-02-24 20:59:14 UTC], ["updated_at", 2017-02-24 20:59:14 UTC]]
2017-02-24T20:59:14.436712+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.436665 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]    (1.9ms)  COMMIT
2017-02-24T20:59:14.441776+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.441724 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Rendering contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb
2017-02-24T20:59:14.442284+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.442237 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   Rendered contact_mailer/contact_email.html.erb (0.4ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.622612+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.622518 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] ContactMailer#contact_email: processed outbound mail in 184.5ms
2017-02-24T20:59:14.749027+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/contacts" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=304ms status=500 bytes=1669
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722589+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722491 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Sent mail to samuelslmoreira@hotmail.com (99.8ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722632+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722588 #4] DEBUG -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Date: Fri, 24 Feb 2017 20:59:14 +0000
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722632+00:00 app[web.1]: From: jp@example.com
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722633+00:00 app[web.1]: To: samuelslmoreira@hotmail.com
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722633+00:00 app[web.1]: Message-ID: <58b09ea298a14_43fc0c75eb9c0103ae@71798652-2827-4935-9282-6b3ae7c47b44.mail>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722634+00:00 app[web.1]: Subject: Contact Form Message
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722634+00:00 app[web.1]: Mime-Version: 1.0
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Type: text/html;
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]:  charset=UTF-8
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722635+00:00 app[web.1]: Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722636+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722636+00:00 app[web.1]: <!DOCTYPE html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]: <html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]:     <head>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722637+00:00 app[web.1]:     </head>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:     <body>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722638+00:00 app[web.1]:             You have received a message from the site's contact form, from Jesse Pinkman, jp@example.com.
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:         <p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722639+00:00 app[web.1]:             
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]:         </p>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]:     </body>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722640+00:00 app[web.1]: </html>
2017-02-24T20:59:14.722825+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.722779 #4]  INFO -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 295ms (ActiveRecord: 4.1ms)
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723286+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723242 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723324+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723287 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723325+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723357+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723324 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6]   
2017-02-24T20:59:14.723390+00:00 app[web.1]: F, [2017-02-24T20:59:14.723357 #4] FATAL -- : [606794a4-3f9b-417c-b3ca-72af4d8bafb6] app/controllers/contacts_controller.rb:15:in `create'
2017-02-24T21:30:27.890702+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=6ms status=200 bytes=2753
2017-02-24T21:30:27.866291+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T21:30:27.866202 #4]  INFO -- : [ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59] Started GET "/" for 188.83.235.112 at 2017-02-24 21:30:27 +0000
2017-02-24T21:30:27.867090+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T21:30:27.867030 #4]  INFO -- : [ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59] Processing by PagesController#home as HTML
2017-02-24T21:30:27.868034+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T21:30:27.867962 #4]  INFO -- : [ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59]   Rendering pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application
2017-02-24T21:30:27.868172+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T21:30:27.868117 #4]  INFO -- : [ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59]   Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (0.0ms)
2017-02-24T21:30:27.869109+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2017-02-24T21:30:27.869058 #4]  INFO -- : [ef1e2185-e94e-4a90-907e-15dad519fd59] Completed 200 OK in 2ms (Views: 1.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
2017-02-24T21:30:28.039850+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-5ed627eba0abe94ba4e2c255c2298f55d9bca9b4ea45ded59ba1705edc5385d0.css" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=f9b48384-ae99-4f9e-b035-6624ef9d2ce6 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T21:30:28.051038+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/application-95163fa38446d1bb6139f870d5fb932af7fa47b347b8951923c32a4565386aa6.js" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=7b1f62bf-5aca-4ac1-b926-5c3219b3ccac fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T21:30:28.279062+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/assets/font-awesome/fontawesome-webfont-2932abf996373e87fbf2e950876b1962f1b57db954a1643ea68831d9fbb74da4.woff2?v=4.6.2" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=d1522ce1-c16b-4525-aa55-08c6f45713c8 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
2017-02-24T21:30:29.186402+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=infinite-forest-28304.herokuapp.com request_id=1cec8754-06b9-4b20-ad32-77976a359e33 fwd="188.83.235.112" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=1ms status=304 bytes=48
```

Comment: Please post the logs by running heroku logs in your app directory in command shell

Comment: If it is a problem with your config please check it, if it is a problem with your rails code please post also that code

Comment: @KcUS_unico Hello, when I do "heroku logs" I receive so many stuff... I don't even know what and where to start copying. I'll do a copy from the logs after receiving an error and meanwhile, which part from the code you would like to see. Any specific controller, mailer or whatever?

Comment: Please juts post the entire heroku logs..

Comment: heroku log posted

Comment: Ok, all I can see from the posted log is that your mailgun account is not yet activated. You should confirm the confirmation email from mailgun. Try again...If error persists please post heroku logs....when in doubt, post entire log

Comment: @KcUS_unico The account is already activated, I even received the e-mail confirmation before coming up with the errors. » "Thanks for using Mailgun! Please confirm your email address by clicking on the link below."

Comment: Ok, but the process seems to be fine. it is even trying or sending the mail until it renders status 500 and throws an error that your mail_gun account is not confirmed. I gues you could double check that. May be you post more of the logs and we can tell you more but so for that's it from my side. I personally do not use mailgun and can't tell you what this error is about...

Comment: So, post a bit more of the logs if you are secure that your mailgun account is fine.

Comment: @KcUS_unico Okay, deal. I will update the post with the all logs I can come across. The MailChimp account seems fine. When I asked to resend the confirmation link it even said: "Looks like this account has already been activated." Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Read the error message:

```
Net::SMTPFatalError (554 Please activate your Mailgun account. Check your inbox or log in to your control panel to resend the activation email.
```

Just activate your account.

Comment: The account has been activated since the beginning as it says "Looks like this account has already been activated." but still, it doesn't work. When I ask to resend the activation I receive a "Server Error/An internal server error occurred" from MailGun. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Sorry it didn't work. Unfortunately, these logs only say that the account is not activated. Sendgrid is a another mail provider that offers also a free plan and works well  with heroku.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. As the logs say and as @GrahamSlick already answered, your mailgun account is not verified. If you claim that the account is verified make sure that the credentials you used in 
your *config/environment.rb* are the correct ones that belong to the verified account and ensure that heroku uses the correct credentials. The logs say that your account is not verified. May be you want to check your settings with mailgun again and see whether they tell you something about having an inactive account. Good luck.

Comment: The account has been activated since the beginning as it says "Looks like this account has already been activated." but still, it doesn't work. When I ask to resend the activation I receive a "Server Error/An internal server error occurred" from MailGun. Thanks for your help anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You have to add a domain, verified it then you can send mails from mailgun.

Comment: If you already added domain and still not work then you can add ticket on mailgun support to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the exact same issue. I even tried with just CURL to make sure it had nothing to do with rails or heroku. I double checked that my domain was validated.

I ended up opening a support ticket. They got back to me within a few hours and said "now its good to go" and sure enough it works.

So it's either bugs on their end, or they purposefully require manual oversight for some accounts. Not a great first impression, but it's good to see their support responded quickly.